# ResourceDictionary organization in WPF style library

Tags: c#, xaml, resourcedictionary, wpf-4.0

We have a WPF library that contains styles that are used in many of our products. It is organized as follows. Each indented level is merged into the library above

```
WpfResources.xaml
  Color.xaml
  ButtonStyle.xaml
    Color.xaml
  OtherStyle.xaml
    Color.xaml
  SliderStyle.xaml
    Color.xaml
```

The problem with this approach is that as you can see Color.xaml is added to each and every control style I add. This might and I'm not sure give a performance hit. All colors brushes, margins etc in Color.xaml are frozen though.

If I remove Color.xaml from the control ResourceDictionaries the visual studio designer will start complaining about missing StaticResources for colors and other things declared in Color.xaml. I could replace them by DynamicResources but that is not wise performance wise.

Any ideas on a better organization of styles?

Answer (score 1):

In our application, we have a `ResourceDictionary` only for colors. So *every* color in our app is loaded in this files. Then we have our Styles and Templates `XAML` files for all controls, not separated ones like you put it.

One thing I've learned is, if you're repeating something, it could be better. Here's our `App.xaml` file just for an example. Keep in mind that with one `Color.xaml` you can make a lot of Themes/Skins!
When someone asks for a a new style, it only takes about 10 minutes to get it done! Here it is:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Cmp.Wpf;component/CmpEstilos/Colors.xaml" /> <!-- Our Colors are here! -->
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Cmp.Wpf;component/CmpEstilos/Styles.xaml" /> <!-- Our Styles are here! -->
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Cmp.Wpf;component/CmpTemplates/Templates.xaml" /> <!-- Our Templates are here! -->
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

This code is inside `App.xaml` - just to remind you.
Nothing against your approach but I think that it would be easier to maintain if you have one file responsible for each "responsibility".

Good luck.

Comment: So you add an App.xaml to your library to allow the VS designer to resolve your StaticResources?

Comment: @Wouter Yes. When we want to change a theme. We call a method to reload these files with a different `Color.xaml` one.

Comment: The problem is that the VS2013 (and 2012) designer does not resolve a ResouceDictionary from a library when it has code behind.